# ExpandableListView with 2 items every row, get child values

Tags: android, expandablelistview, children, expandablelistadapter

I am using `ExpandableListActivity` in combination with `ExpandListAdapter`.

**My layout:**

```
---------------------------------
|  <TextView>                   |
|                               |
|-------------------------------|
| <ExpandableList>            | |
|  group1                     | |
|   child1: textView editText | |
|   child2: textView switch   | |
|  group2                     | |
|   child1: textView textView | |
|-------------------------------| 
| <footerView>                  |
|  [button]                     |
---------------------------------
```

Here is my child_layout (removed unnecessary parts):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChild"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etChild"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChild2"
        android:layout_width="600px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchChild"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="NO"
        android:textOn="YES"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I add button, switch or textView to each child:

```
    Switch swc = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchChild);
    EditText etc = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etChild);
    TextView tvc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild2);

    if (groupPosition == 0) {
        swc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        etc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (childPosition == 0) 
            etc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (childPosition == 1) 
            etc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (childPosition == 2) {
            tvc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvc.setText(GlobalVariables.currentSelectedCar);
        }
    }
```

So, each child has a `TextView` which won't change plus one of `EditText/TextView/Switch` which is editable by the user. I would like to get each children's editable item values when I click the button at the bottom.

Comment: Are u Achieved this thing? I am looking for same but getting problem to retrive data from the childview

Comment: Contact me if you are still having problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can handle this in a similar fashion to how you would get information contained within one item of a regular `ListView`. The [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnChildClickListener%28android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener%29) has built in methods that allow you to find out which item was clicked. Once you know which item in the list was clicked you can simply extract the values from the individual views associated with that item. I would do the following:

(1) `setOnGroupClickListener` for your `ExpandableListView`. The `onGroupClick` listener gets, among other thigns, the view that was selected along with its position in the list.

(2) Once you know which item in the list was selected you should be able to extract the data in one of two ways. If the data you're looking for is fixed, use the position indicator to retrieve that data from the adapter that is backing the list. If you're looking for a view within that selected item - which it sounds like you are - use `findViewById` on the view that is returned. For example - as the `onGroupClick` method supplied View v as an argument

```
String input = v.findViewById(R.id.etChild).getText().toString();
```

Calling `findViewById` on the view supplied by `onGroupClick` should allow you to look within that view for a child view of the id you supply. That way you can extract the data from the input fields within each list item.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I spend a lot of time with `ExpandableListActivity` and `ExpandListAdapter`, it seems your suggestion is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Idea From #Rarw

```
TextView input = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.child_item_elv);
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "child clicked : " + input.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

this one works, inside of `OnGroupListener`